# Message application on Android (mms)

Tags: android, github, message, mms

I'm trying to make a modification on the default sms in android phones.

I have downloaded the source code from the following link

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms

The link contains (src, res, mainfest)
I opened it as a project on Eclipse using the following steps:

file > import > exsisting project in the workspace
but the problem is that the Eclipse doesn't see it as android project and so I can't install it on emulator

What should I do?

Comment: this can only be be complie in android NDK this will help you `http://tthtlc.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/how-to-compile-the-android-ndk-examples-using-command-line-tools/`

Comment: But the project doesn't contain native code 
why do I have to compile it using NDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps

file > New > Android Project > select "create project from existing source" > click on "Browse" Button and select project.

it may help you.

Comment: then create new android project and copy all necessary files into new project and then run your project into emulator.

Comment: This will generate an error in R file ... R file will no be generated

Comment: after that build your project or clean your project.

Comment: I did that .. but the R file is not generatated also

Answer (score 0):

the API level of the github may be higher than you are using.
Or the project property may be missed of your downloaded project. please check..